# Запись словаря в с CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть такой словарь

```
`{'one' : ['1', '2', 3'], 'two' : ['4', '5', '6]}`
```

я его хочу записать в CSV файл.
Сделал колонки

```
with open('new_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_file:
writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=';')
writer.writerow(['ONE', 'TWO']}
```

Как мне записать словарь чтоб получилось вот так (может через pandas как то можно записать в csv?):

```
ONE;  TWO;
1      4
2      5
3      6
```

Comment: Гляньте здесь - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49882935/python-dict-to-csv-in-columns-format

Answer (score 2):

Я бы делал через  Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
dt={'one' : ['1', '2', '3'], 'two' : ['4', '5', '6']}
df=pd.DataFrame(dt,columns=dt.keys())
df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Содержимое файла выглядит так:

```
one,two
1,4
2,5
3,6
```

Нужен другой разделитель -  используйте соответствующий параметр (sep)